# yii1 pagination with url-manager

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, yii-url-manager

i have problem with yii1 pagination
this is my url manage config:

```
'rules' => array(
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<slug:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'adminproduces/producelist/<slug:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => 'adminproduces/producelist',
'adminrequests/requestlist/<slug:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => 'adminrequests/requestlist',
'userrequest/neworder/<type:\w+>/<slug:\w+>' => 'userrequest/neworder',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
),
```

every thing ok ,but when i use pagination the created url is not matched with my urlmanger config
this my requested Url:
"/adminrequests/requestlist/digital/status10021"
that match with line 5 of url manger
....
in same page i use

```
<?php
// the pagination widget with some options to mess
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array('pages' => $pages));
?>
```

but when run project the link create this link for next pages
"adminrequests/requestlist/status10021?slug=digital&page=2"
insted of "adminrequests/requestlist/digital/status10021?page=2"
why?
can ypu help me please ?
when i manualy type "adminrequests/requestlist/digital/status10021?page=2" in address bar next page loaad correctly....
but pagination dosent make correct links...

Comment: Can you show us where `$pages` come from? Probably you initialize `$pages` in your controller, can you post it?

Comment: $total = OieOrder::model()->count($criteria);
            //$criteria->limit=10;
   $pages = new CPagination($total);
   //$pages->setPageSize(Yii::app()->params['listPerPage']);
   $pages->setPageSize(2);
   $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
   //$pages->params=array('slug'=>$_GET['slug'],'id'=>$_GET['id']);
   $list = OieOrder::model()->findAll($criteria);
   $view_variable['requests'] = $list;
   $view_variable['pages'] = $pages;
   $view_variable['brn_slug'] = $_GET['slug'];
   $this->render('requestlist' , $view_variable);

Answer (score 0):

[Yii's CPagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination) has `route` property. You can use this for your need. Something like this:

```
$pages->route = "adminrequests/requestlist/digital/status10021";
```

You should usually set **the part of url which is before starting pagination part.**